# Firebase Authentication Issues Juggling Anonymous And AuthProvider Accounts

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having issues figuring out how to implement the functionality for my current tasks. I will try to explain the situation simply:

The app is an Angular 2 webapp that uses Firebase for authentication. when the app loads up, the user is automatically authenticated anonymously (since we have database and file storage rules that are set to "auth != null".

Then later in the app there is a feature that the user can only use when authenticated through an auth provider (Google). If I try to just sign in with Google it saying that the user is already signed in.

So we can sign out, and then try to authenticate with Google. But then what if the user closes the auth popup box or denies giving the app permissions? Then the user is not authenticated at all!

And if we re-authenticate anonymously if the Google sign-in fails then we have a completely different username (created from the uid) which is very weird UX for the user.

Perhaps I am not thinking about it correctly, but I just don't see any good solution for what I'm trying to do. Hopefully, someone else can find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) APIs?

Comment: As Michael pointed out, you could always sign in the user anonymously and then when a google provider is needed, try to upgrade the anonymous user by linking a google provider to it (linkWIthPopup) and if that fails, the anonymous user is still logged in.

Comment: The linking method is not a good solution because the accounts cannot be linked to multiple anonymous user accounts. If user authenticates with google, then signs out and gets a new anonymous user id he will not be able to authenticate with google again.